# \textwidth within \resizebox

Tags: tables, graphics, scaling, multicolumn

I want to the final row of a table to display the notes, spanning across all columns, using `\multicolumn{#}{p{\textwidth}}{}`. This does not work properly in connection with resize, because `textwidth` keeps the same value but the measurement is scaled downwards.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr} \hline
aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa\\ \hline
\multicolumn{9}{p{\textwidth}}{Notes: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.}
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: resizing tables almost always results in poor results, it leads to inconsistent font sizes. It is almost always better to use one of the class specified font sizes such as \normalsize or \small, and then adjust the table layout so it fits

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `threeparttablex`, though it is not perfect (a little too wide in the right)

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}

\noindent
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr} \hline aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa &
      aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa &
      aaaaaaaa\\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}%
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \note Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
      sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I still have a preference to stick to resize and the only-tabular version, because this is part of an automatized solution which works fine for me otherwise. The problem could probably be solved if I could access the scale factor used by resize, this would allow to calculate the correct textwidth.

Comment: @cth `\resizebox` can not calculate the scale factor until after the table has been set, in general the argument to that `p` column could affect the width of the table and so change the scale factor.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to save/calculate the **real** width of the table

```
\newsavebox\tableBox
\sbox\tableBox{\begin{tabular}{rrrr...}...\end{tabular}} % without the \multicolumn line
```

then

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{rrrr...}
    ...
    \multicolumn{9}{p{\wd\tableBox}}{...}
  \end{tabular}%
}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newsavebox\tableBox
\sbox\tableBox{%
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr} \hline
aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa\\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr} \hline
aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa\\ \hline
\multicolumn{9}{p{\wd\tableBox}}{Notes: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.}
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```